# Retrieve most frequent value for each couple of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm working with a df having 3 columns: 'Latitude', 'Longitude' and 'street_type'.

The 'street_type' column has multiple values like 'rectilinear', 'roundabout' exc.

I would like to retrieve the most frequent value for each couple of values 'Latitude' and 'Longitude'.

I tried using the group by expression like this one:

```
df=df.group_by(['Latitude','Longitude'])[['steet_type']].sum().reset_index()
```

It returns me the df with the group by but I would like to have the most frequent value with its count and the coordinate for that value.

The street_type column has only strings si I used the get_dummies method to have only numbers. Was it a good practice or not for the `groupby()` and a `sum()`?

Thank you in advance!

```py
data = {'Latitude'=[-41.794,-41.733,-41.335,-41.794],'Longitude'=[-12.344,-12.456,-12.929,-12.344],'street_type'={'rectilinear','roundabout','intersection','rectilinear']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['street_type'])
df = df.groupby(['Latitude','Longitude'])[['street_type_rectilinear','street_type_roundabout','street_type_intersection']].sum().reset_index()
```

The output from `groupby` snd `sum()`

| Latitude | Longitude | street_type_rectilinear | street_type_roundabout | street_type_intersection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -41.794 | -12.344 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| -41.733 | -12.456 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| -41.335 | -12.929 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| -41.794 | -12.344 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

same result for `agg(pd.Series.mode)`
same result for `agg(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]).reset_index()`

The desidered output is:

| Latitude | Longitude | street_type_rectilinear | street_type_roundabout | street_type_intersection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -41.794 | -12.344 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| -41.733 | -12.456 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| -41.335 | -12.929 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| -41.794 | -12.344 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

**EDITED THE QUESTION WITH SAMPLE CODE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom lambda function for first `mode`:

```
df = (df.groupby(['Latitude', 'Longitude'])['street_type']
        .agg(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
        .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `agg` and `pd.Series.mode`:

```
print(df.groupby(['Latitude', 'Longitude'])['street_type'].agg(pd.Series.mode).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   Latitude  Longitude   street_type
0   -41.794    -12.344   rectilinear
1   -41.733    -12.456    roundabout
2   -41.335    -12.929  intersection
```

Comment: Unfortunately both method ```sum()``` and ```agg(pd.Series.mode)``` behave the same, giving me the same output, that is the same one I wrote in the question.

Comment: ```data = {'Latitude'=[-41.794,-41.733,-41.335,-41.794],'Longitude'=[-12.344,-12.456,-12.929,-12.344],'street_type'=['rectilinear','roundabout','intersection','rectilinear']```

Comment: I edited the question, unfortunately none of the given answer worked for me. The output wont change.